# Microsoft Edge browser completely ignoring div width

Tags: html, css, sass, microsoft-edge

Why does Microsoft Edge browser ignore div width, which is 80rem (800px)?
Here is website for live reference: //removed

Normal way (like it should display): 
[image]

And here is the way Microsoft Edge displays:

[image]

HTML:

```
<section class="section-features">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-1-of-3">
            <div class="feature-box">
              <a href="#" class="feature-box__link js--scroll-to-ari">
                <img class="feature-box__img" src="./img/arikinnisvara.png" alt="Ärikinnisvarahaldus">
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="feature-box__link js--scroll-to-ari">
                <h2 class="heading heading--sub feature-box__heading">Ärikinnisvara- <span class="feature-box__break">haldus</span></h2>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-1-of-3">
            <div class="feature-box">
              <a href="#" class="js--scroll-to-elamu">
                <img class="feature-box__img" src="./img/elamu.png" alt="Elamuhaldus">
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="feature-box__link js--scroll-to-elamu">
                <h2 class="heading heading--sub feature-box__heading">Elamu- <span class="feature-box__break">haldus</span></h2>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-1-of-3">
            <div class="feature-box">
              <a href="#" class="js--scroll-to-kindlustus">
                <img class="feature-box__img" src="./img/kindlustus.png" alt="Kindlustuskahjude hindamine">
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="js--scroll-to-elamu feature-box__link">
                <h2 class="heading heading--sub feature-box__heading">Kindlustuskahjude <span class="feature-box__break">hindamine</span></h2>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="arrow-box">
            <a href="#" class="arrow-box__link js--scroll-to-ari"><span class="arrow-box__span arrow-box__span--1"></span><span class="arrow-box__span arrow-box__span--2"></span><span class="arrow-box__span arrow-box__span--3"></span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

CSS (SCSS):

```
.feature-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;

  @include respond(tab-port) {
    margin-bottom: -3.5rem;
  }

  @include respond(phone) {
    margin-bottom: -5rem;
  }

  &__img {
    margin-right: 2rem;
    outline: none;
    -moz-user-focus: ignore;

    @include respond(tab-port) {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    @include respond(phone) {
      margin-right: 0;
    }
  }

  &__link .feature-box__img {
    outline: none;
  }

  &__link {
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  &__heading {
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  &__break {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Grid used (for row and col-1-of-3 class reference):

```
// GRID
$grid-width: 80rem;
$gutter-vertical: 8rem;
$gutter-vertical-small: 6rem;
$gutter-horizontal: 6rem;    

.row {
        max-width: $grid-width;
        margin: 0 auto;

    &:not(:last-child) {
        margin-bottom: $gutter-vertical;

        @include respond(tab-port) {
            margin-bottom: $gutter-vertical-small;
        }
    }

    @include respond(tab-port) {
        max-width: 50rem;
        padding: 0 3rem;
    }

    @include clearfix;

    [class^="col-"] {
        float: left;

        &:not(:last-child) {
            margin-right: $gutter-horizontal;

            @include respond(tab-port) {
                margin-right: 0;
                margin-bottom: $gutter-vertical-small;
            }
        }

        @include respond(tab-port) {
            width: 100% !important;
        }
    }

    .col-1-of-2 {
        width: calc((100% - #{$gutter-horizontal}) / 2);

    }

    .col-1-of-3 {
        width: calc((100% - 2 * #{$gutter-horizontal}) / 3);
    }

    .col-2-of-3 {
        width: calc(2 * ((100% - 2 * #{$gutter-horizontal}) / 3) + #{$gutter-horizontal});
    }

    .col-1-of-4 {
        width: calc((100% - 3 * #{$gutter-horizontal}) / 4);
    }

    .col-2-of-4 {
        width: calc(2 * ((100% - 3 * #{$gutter-horizontal}) / 4) + #{$gutter-horizontal});
    }

    .col-3-of-4 {
        width: calc(3 * ((100% - 3 * #{$gutter-horizontal}) / 4) + 2 * #{$gutter-horizontal});
    }

}
```

What might be causing this problem? Any suggestions, please?

Comment: It might be a version issue

Comment: it works perfect for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your grid system is not perfect.
IE seems to be unable to calculate correctly width of columns and total width of all three columns is a bit larger than 100%.

I'd recommend you to use `display: flex` for row instead of `float: left` for columns.

Codepen [demo](https://codepen.io/3rdthemagical/pen/QBMmrR?editors=0100).

**Css:**

```
.row {
  display: flex;
}

[class^="col-"] {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```css
.row {
  max-width: 80rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}
.row:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 8rem;
}
.row [class^="col-"] {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.row [class^="col-"]:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 6rem;
}
.row .col-1-of-2 {
  width: calc((100% - 6rem) / 2);
}
.row .col-1-of-3 {
  background: red;
  width: calc((100% - 2 * 6rem) / 3);
}
.row .col-2-of-3 {
  width: calc(2 * ((100% - 2 * 6rem) / 3) + 6rem);
}
.row .col-1-of-4 {
  width: calc((100% - 3 * 6rem) / 4);
}
.row .col-2-of-4 {
  width: calc(2 * ((100% - 3 * 6rem) / 4) + 6rem);
}
.row .col-3-of-4 {
  width: calc(3 * ((100% - 3 * 6rem) / 4) + 2 * 6rem);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-1-of-3">1</div>
  <div class="col-1-of-3">1</div>
  <div class="col-1-of-3">1</div>
</div>
```

Or you can use dirty hack: set 99% instead of 100% while calculation columns width.

`width: calc((99% - 2 * #{$gutter-horizontal}) / 3);`

Comment: Now there is someone who knows what he is talking about- problem fixed, cheers :)!

Answer (score -2):

this is working fine. Kindly update your microsoft EDGE. this is working fine at my end

Comment: Okay so Browserestack is clearly not working like it should even after I cleared cache just now.. I also tested it on another PC, which has Windows 10 installed there and it is displaying it still the wrong way and it is not even offering any updates..